# xslt1.0 (firefox): reformatting xml code based on the total number of different values present

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting, xslt-1.0, max

This one I really think is not possible to solve through XSLT, so that I will have to do something with JS or just do not implement.
But before giving up, of course I have to post here to see if I am wrong and XSLT can do this kind of logic.

EDIT: now I'm starting to see that it is possible, getting closer

EDIT2: I have to correct a mistake in the XML code provided. The solution should be able to handle multiple nodes with the same values.

The concept is that I need to re-format the code including empty tags that reflect the total number of different values. Difficult to explain, much easier to understand looking at the code.

Initial XML code

```
<data>
    <prot seq="AAA">
        <node num="4">1345</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="BBB">
        <node num="7">6666</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="CCC">
        <node num="10">3e33</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="DDD">
        <node num="4">1345</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="EEE">
        <node num="10">3e33</node>
    </prot>
</data>
```

And the wished output

```
<root>
    <prot seq="AAA">
        <node num="4">1345</node><node num="7">-</node><node num="10">-</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="BBB">
        <node num="4">-</node><node num="7">6666</node><node num="10">-</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="CCC">
        <node num="4">-</node><node num="7">-</node><node num="10">3e33</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="DDD">
        <node num="4">1345</node><node num="7">-</node><node num="10">-</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="EEE">
        <node num="4">-</node><node num="7">-</node><node num="10">3e33</node>
    </prot>
</root>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

EDIT3: from Dimitri solution, I've ended up with this simplified solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="kNodeByNum" match="/data/prot/node" use="@num"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/prot"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/data/prot">
  <xsl:variable name="current_num" select="node/@num"/>
  <xsl:variable name="current_value" select="node"/>
  <prot seq="{@seq}">
    <xsl:for-each select="/data/prot/node[
    generate-id()
    =
    generate-id(key('kNodeByNum', @num)[1])
    ]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@num = $current_num">
          <node num="{@num}"><xsl:value-of select="$current_value"/></node>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <node num="{@num}">-</node>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </prot>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this code also cannot handle the number of nodes in firefox and goes in a forever-like loop (and I have to force firefox to close).

But I am thinking that this has nothing to do with the number of nodes but that there is something wrong with the code (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a short and simple (no `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise`) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:param name="pParent" select="/.."/>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
    <xsl:with-param name="pParent" select="$pParent"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="prot">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="../prot/node">
    <xsl:with-param name="pParent" select="."/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node/text()">
  <xsl:param name="pParent" select="/.."/>

  <xsl:variable name="vSameParent" select=
  "boolean(not((../.. | $pParent)[2]))"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(substring('-', 1 +$vSameParent),
                    self::node()[$vSameParent]
                   )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <prot seq="AAA">
        <node num="4">1345</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="BBB">
        <node num="7">6666</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="CCC">
        <node num="10">3e33</node>
    </prot>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<data>
   <prot seq="AAA">
      <node num="4">1345</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">-</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="BBB">
      <node num="4">-</node>
      <node num="7">6666</node>
      <node num="10">-</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="CCC">
      <node num="4">-</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">3e33</node>
   </prot>
</data>
```

**Explanation**:

1. We use and override a modified version of the identity rule -- one which accepts and passes a parameter named `$pParent`.
2. The parameter `$pParent` contains the `node` element that issued `xsl:apply-templates`, part of which is the processing of the current node.
3. We have two templates that override the identity rule. The first overriding template matches any `prot` element. It is almost identical to the identity rule, but it sets the `$pParent` parameter with a meaningful value (this node itself).
4. The second overriding template matches any text node that is a child of any `node` element. Here, depending on whether or not the value of `$pParent` identifies the grandparent of the matched text node, we output respectively, the value of the text node or just `"-"`.
5. The decision what to output is done without using any explicit conditional instruction. Instead, we use the XPath `concat()` function with two arguments, exactly one of which is a non-empty string. To assure this property, we use the boolean variable `$vSameParent`, which is specified in such a way that its value is `true()` exactly when the grand-parent of the matched text node is identical to the node contained in `$pParent`. Finally, we use the fact that when used as a number, a boolean value of `true()` is converted to `1` and a boolean value of `false()` is converted to `0`.

**Update**: This is a new solution -- to the modified by the OP problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNodeByNum" match="node" use="@num"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:param name="pNum"/>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$pNum"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="prot">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "../prot/node
            [generate-id()
            =
             generate-id(key('kNodeByNum', @num)[1])
            ]
   ">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="node/@num"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node/text()">
  <xsl:param name="pNum" select="/.."/>

  <xsl:variable name="vSameNum" select=
  "../@num = $pNum"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(substring('-', 1 +$vSameNum),
                    self::node()[$vSameNum]
                   )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <prot seq="AAA">
        <node num="4">1345</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="BBB">
        <node num="7">6666</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="CCC">
        <node num="10">3e33</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="DDD">
        <node num="4">1345</node>
    </prot>
    <prot seq="EEE">
        <node num="10">3e33</node>
    </prot>
</data>
```

**the new wanted result is produced**:

```
<data>
   <prot seq="AAA">
      <node num="4">1345</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">-</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="BBB">
      <node num="4">-</node>
      <node num="7">6666</node>
      <node num="10">-</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="CCC">
      <node num="4">-</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">3e33</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="DDD">
      <node num="4">1345</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">-</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="EEE">
      <node num="4">-</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">3e33</node>
   </prot>
</data>
```

**Explanation**: The same main ideas as with the original problem, with added **[Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

Comment: Thanks (as starts to be usual) again :) now I'll see what do I understand. However, I've edited the question since the XML initial code that I've posted was too simple. I have to get rid of this redundancy.

Comment: @Gerard: I have updated my answer (look at the end) accordingly. :)

Comment: Thanks again, I'll take a deep look tomorrow, I have to admit that DevNull code was difficult (many things seen for 1st time), but yours is even "worse" :) That usually means a good opportunity to learn more, and I also am very curious to see if this muenchian approach will be able to operate with a huge number of nodes.

Comment: @Gerard: The Muenchian method is the most efficient grouping method (O(N) for creating the index, then O(1) for any lookup.) -- especially with huge number of nodes. A well-implemented key index is similar to a hash table. Also, don't forget that the solution of DevNull doesn't yet target your updated question -- it also is bound to become more complicated than its initial variant.

Comment: So, I'm having troubles in understanding `<xsl:param name="pNum" select="/.."/>`, you receive a variable, what does the select do here? And `<xsl:template match="node/text()">`, which node are you matching? EDIT: I see that those explanations are in the 1st code

Comment: @Gerard: `/..` is necessary in order to specify to the XSLT processor that the parameter is of node-set type. If we omit this, then an operation like `|` (union) will result in an XSLT parser error, because the XSLT processor thinks the param is a atomic item (not node or node-set) and `I` is only defined on node-sets.

Comment: @Gerard: The meaning of: `<xsl:template match="node/text()">` is that this template matches any text-node that is a child of a `node` element.

Comment: From your code, I've ended with a similar code (below EDIT3 in the question) that is easier to understand for me. But, the fact that uses the muenchian method should allow me to implement easily to my code. But it is not the case, the for-each keeps firefox thinking for ever. I am starting to thing that this is a problem that has nothing to do with the number of nodes. Do you see anything wrong with the code??

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with the code, but that the price of going through all the nodes is just to high. Maybe you can see any xslt alternative that avoids this costly search? My B plan is to build a series of tags that reroduce the different num values with javascript (the one that generates the XML in my code).

Comment: @Gerard: Your code runs OK for me (with Saxon). Maybe the XML document has some other peculiarities or you aren't using exactly this code. Have you tried running the transformation with another XSLT processor and if so, do you have the same problem with it?

Comment: @Gerard: How big is your XML? can you provide it so that we can run the transform and verify that it really runs slow?

Comment: It is not easy, since the code is a .csv file, transformed to .xml by javascript and then, to html by xslt. But, I've confirmed that the code works by 1) building a .csv file very small, and 2) waiting forever with a normal file. In both cases the code is well executed. Then it is clear that it is just that the code needs time to be executed I would say.

Comment: @Gerard: In case you can provide an XML file (maybe the slow part of the processing is the JS transforming the CSV to XML) of the size that makes processing slow, I can run it on my machines and verify.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this in FireFox, but it works in Xalan and Saxon...

*Edit: Tested in FireFox 8.0 and added comments to the stylesheet*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Identity Template - Anything not matched by another template will be 
  copied without changes.-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Change the name of the "data" element to "root" element.-->
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="prot">
    <!--Save the current "num" attribute from the child "node" element.-->
    <xsl:variable name="vCurrNum" select="node/@num"/>    
    <prot>
      <!--This will pass all attributes of "prot" through the identity template.-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!--This will process the the current "node" element and also any "node" elements in other
      "prot" elements that don't have the same "num" attribute as the current "node".-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node|/*/prot/node[@num != $vCurrNum]">
        <!--This passes the current "num" attribute to the "node" template that gets matched below.-->
        <xsl:with-param name="pNum" select="$vCurrNum"/>
        <!--This will sort the "node" elements based on their "num" attribute.-->
        <xsl:sort select="@num" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </prot>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node">
    <!--This is the "num" attribute value passed in the xsl:apply-templates above.-->
    <xsl:param name="pNum"/>
      <!--This will pass all attributes of "node" through the identity template.-->
      <xsl:choose>
        <!--If the current "num" attribute is the same as the "num" attribute passed to 
        the xsl:apply-templates ($pNum), output the value.-->
        <xsl:when test="@num = $pNum">          
          <node>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>  
          </node>          
        </xsl:when>
        <!--This ensures we only get one of the other "node" elements. (The first "node" with that "num".)-->
        <xsl:when test="not(parent::prot[preceding-sibling::prot[node[@num = current()/@num]]])">
          <node>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>            
          </node>
        </xsl:when>
        <!--Ignore any other repeated node/num combinations.-->
        <xsl:otherwise/>                
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your XML input, it generates the wanted output:

```
<root>
   <prot seq="AAA">
      <node num="4">1345</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">-</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="BBB">
      <node num="4">-</node>
      <node num="7">6666</node>
      <node num="10">-</node>
   </prot>
   <prot seq="CCC">
      <node num="4">-</node>
      <node num="7">-</node>
      <node num="10">3e33</node>
   </prot>
</root>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it will take a while to follow what you do here, but thanks for the very fast answer :)

Comment: @Gerard - You're very welcome. I can add some comments to the code if that will help.

Comment: @Gerard - Comments added. Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: thank you very much for the comments. I have understood what you've done :) The problem is that when implementing this to my code firefox just crashed. Then I've realised that this is because my code posted here was too simple. Please take a look at the new code (question edited). I will try to figure out for myself how can I handle that in the meantime :)

Comment: @Gerard - I updated the stylesheet. I added an additional `xsl:when`.

Comment: well, that´s it. Thank you very much, quite interesting code to learn from. Unfortunately, when the number of nodes in the XML file is big, firefox just gets frozen. I've changed the apply-templates for a for-each (the code works as well with this example), and it is like this loop is ethernal. Is there any alternative to write "node|/*/prot/node[@num != $vCurrNum]"? I guess this group of nodes is too big for firefox to handle?